# USB Clamping for OV protection

Tags: usb

For our current design we require overvoltage protection on USB D+ and D-. I am aware that for USB, the total line capacitance of the line should be less than 10pF.

We are planning to use a circuit like this for OV protection, the diodes are schottky diodes such as **1PS10SB82** with capacitance 1 pF. Could you guys suggest that this clamp section will not affect USB D+ and D-.

[image]

Comment: Isn't USB at 5V nominal (?) and then there are the data excursions above and below that voltage to take into account?

Comment: I second that. To my knowledge, the differential pair goes 2V8 - 3V6

Comment: Take a look at this integrated solution and appnote: http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10753.pdf

Comment: @Andyaka USB power supply is 5V (max), the maximum voltage on the data lines is 3V6 (full-bandwidth) and they are non-5V-tolerant (according to the spec).